# Issue accessing contents of array of character pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am going through The C Programming Language by K&R and trying to understand character pointers and arrays.

I am creating a function in C that reads multiple lines from `stdin` and stores the lines (`char*`) in an array of character pointers (`char* []`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {MAXINPUT = 1024, MAXLINES = 100};

/* Reads at most `maxLines` lines and stores them in an array of char pointers. Returns number of lines read. */
int readlines(char* lineptr[], int maxLines);

/* Takes a single line input from stdin and stores it in str. Returns str length. */
int getInputLine(char* str, int maxInput);

int main(int argc, char** argv) { ... }

int readlines(char* lineptr[], int maxLines) {
    /* Return number of lines read. */
    int numLines = 0;
    /* Buffer to store current line being read. */
    char currentLine[MAXINPUT];

    /* Terminate loop when enter is pressed at empty input or number of lines exceeds max. */
    while(getInputLine(currentLine,MAXINPUT) && numLines < maxLines) {
        /* Address of current line's first character is set to the appropriate index at lineptr. */
        lineptr[numLines] = currentLine;

        /* Both currentLine and lineptr[numLines] print accurately (note they are the same). */
        printf("CURRENT LINE:\t %s\n",currentLine);
        printf("lineptr[%d]:\t %s\n",numLines,lineptr[numLines]);

        numLines++;
    }

    /* ISSUE: Outside the loop, lineptr does NOT print anything. */
    printf("\nLOOPING\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n",i,lineptr[i]);
    }

    /* ISSUE: currentLine (which should be the last line entered) ALSO does not print outside the while. */
    printf("\ncurrentLine: %s",currentLine);

    return numLines;
}
```

My issue is that in the `while()`, the contents of `lineptr` and `currentLine` print accurately. But outside the `while()`, both `lineptr` and `currentLine` do not print anything.

And of course, this issue persists when I try to read lines into a `char* []` in the `main()` and try to print its contents.

Why is it that the contents at the addresses being accessed by `lineptr` are printing inside the loop but not outside? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: All of your `lineptr[i]` point to the same buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have a single buffer called `currentLine` into which you read text.  Then you assign the address of `currentLine` to your `lineptr[i]`, and proceed to overwrite its contents with new text.  So, all your `lineptr`s essentially point to the same one location, which is the address of `currentLine`, and `currentLine` contains only the last line that you read.  I suppose the loop does not print anything because the last line you read is empty.

So, to get this to work, you need to read a line into `currentLine`, measure its length, use `malloc()` to allocate enough memory for that line, copy the line from `currentLine` to the allocated memory, and store the pointer to the allocated memory in `lineptr[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
    lineptr[numLines] = currentLine;
```

just assigns a pointer to `lineptr[numLines]`. There are couple of issues with that:

1. Every line points to the same pointer.
2. The pointer is invalid after you return from the function.

You need to use something akin to:

```
    lineptr[numLines] = strdup(currentLine);
```

Remember that `strdup` is not a standard C library function. If your platform does not support it, you can implement it very easily.

```
char* strdup(char const* in)
{
    char* ret = malloc(strlen(in)+1);
    return strcpy(ret, in);
}
```